# Entity Framework Object comparison

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having troubles comparing objects In entity Framework 4.0. After googling for a while I found a blog post in 2008 which stated what my problem was and why it is occuring.[Blog post describing my problem in depth](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2008/02/26/entity-framework-comparison-frustration-explained.aspx).

To sum up the blog post you cannot do a custom object comparison with the EF framework at all. For example

```
public Foo
{
public int ID{get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
//I overrode the .Equals AND the == operator
}

public getFoo(Foo target)
{
   DC.foos.FirstOrDefault(x => x == target);
}
```

**System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Foo' Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.**

This is [by design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738686%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) according to MicroSoft.

***Can someone point me in a direction to find if this sort of Object comparison is supported if I do some magic interface or magic overload?***  thank you very much!

Comment: when comparing Objects use the Equals or IEquatable interface when comparing values for example does "X" == "Y" don't use Equals unless you do some (object) casting can you also explain what you are trying to do more indepth? thanks paste your example

Comment: @DJKRAZE. I have custom objects created to represent Business objects which map to EF entities. In these objects I overrode the implicit conversion operator, the .Equals, the ==, the get hashcode. I did this so i can make my code more readably when I do comparisions between the EF objects and my BOL object.

Comment: Why don't you just implement the comparison in the FirstOrDefault statement itself? Overriding the Equals function is in fact less clear.

Comment: @Dabblernl I feel x == y is clearer then x.foo == y.foo && x.bar == y.bar && ..... You are saying it is not, can you explain why it is less clear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since EF needs to translate your LINQ statements to SQL statements, you can't do this. If you have complex comparison logic in your overridden `Equals()` method you will have to duplicate that in the LINQ statement.

Since LINQ uses deferred execution you could probably encapsulate that logic in a method that returns an `IQueryable<T>` you can incorporate elsewhere.

Here's an example:

```
public IQueryable<Foo> FoosEqualTo(IQueryable<Foo> allFoos, Foo target) {
    return from foo in allFoos
           where foo.Id == target.Id // or other comparison logic...
           select foo;
}

public Foo getFoo(Foo target) {
    return FoosEqualTo(DC.foos, target).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Can you mock up an example for the Iqueryable method. According to the msdn I cannot use ANY method returns, only primitive datatypes

Comment: @ Yuck . I was hoping for a way to use my overrode equality operators but, your saying i am screwed and i just need to imbed that logic into a method. I apreciate the help. If no one can figure out some cool magic I will end up going with your answer. Again thank you very much

Comment: @gh9 I wouldn't say you're "screwed", it's just a different way of looking at how you bundle the logic. The `FoosEqualTo()` method is still reusable so you maintain that benefit of writing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using [LinqKit](http://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/)'s [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and reflection. Alternatively, you could use reflection to generate a chain of `Where` `Expressions` to do the same thing.

I don't have time to put together an example, but I'm pretty sure you can do it this way.